# Looking at Video that contains mockery to Islam

Tags: fiqh, shirk, kufr, aqidah, movies

What's the ruling on someone who intentionally watch a joke video or a movie that contains (or may contain) mockery to Islam? Will we be considered as an apostate If we're watching such video/movie intentionally and laughing at it (without believing that such thing is acceptable)?

Comment: What does it mean to "not believe it is acceptable" if you are laughing at it? Laughing is done when you don't have problems with the joke. For example, if someone was making fun of you, you certainly wouldn't laugh because you aren't ok with that. Then, what about Islam?

Comment: No man it's quite different, check this out https://islamqa.info/en/answers/163627/guideline-on-what-actions-and-words-are-regarded-as-mocking-religion

Comment: "With regard to smiling or laughing when hearing such words, that makes the one who does it a partner in sin with the one who says them, if it stems from his being pleased with and accepting those things, as Allah, may He be exalted, says: “certainly in that case you would be like them” [an-Nisa’ 4:140]. But if it did not stem from his being pleased with and accepting those things, then it is a major sin which indicates that reverence for Allah and His symbols is not firmly established in his heart."